# Google Maps API v3 infowindow close event/callback?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I like to keep track of any and all infowindows that are open on my Google Maps interface (I store their names in an array), but I can't figure out how to remove them from my array when they are closed via the "x" in the upper right hand corner of each one.

Is there some sort of callback I can listen for? Or maybe I can do something like 
`addListener("close", infowindow1, etc` ?

Answer (score 183, accepted):

there's an event for infowindows call `closeclick` that can help you

```
var currentMark;
var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: 'im an info windows'
        });
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
          infoWindow.open(map, this);
          currentMark = this;

});
google.maps.event.addListener(infoWindow,'closeclick',function(){
   currentMark.setMap(null); //removes the marker
   // then, remove the infowindows name from the array
});
```

Comment: Note that this does not fire when another marker nearby is clicked and that marker is closed automatically... such as when a scroll takes place to make sure the info window is in the visible bounds of the map.

Answer (score 19):

The only consistent solution I've found here is to retain a pointer to the `infoWindow` and check its `.getMap()` method whenever you need to validate whether it has been closed.

The reason for this is that clicking another element can cause the infoWindow to be dismissed for other reasons... without the `closeclick` event firing.

```
var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({ content: 'Something to put here.' });
infoWindow.open(map, infoWindow);

setInterval(function ()
{
    console.log("infoWindow is bound to map: "+(infoWindow.getMap() ? true : false));

}, 1000);
```

... If you literally only care if the `infoWindow` was closed using the "X" button, then monitoring `closeclick` is fine. However, there are other reasons it may be or have been closed.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var closeBtn = $('.gm-style-iw').next();
closeBtn.click(function(){
    //other things you want to do when close btn is click
    that.infowindow.close();
});
```

I overwrite this click function because the click button won't work in safari after I change the css/position of it.

Answer (score 1):

```
infoWindow.addListener('closeclick', ()=>{
  // Handle focus manually.
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplifying and extending the [most upvoted solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6777885/4028977), you can create the marker during the handling of the marker click event, letting you package its removal due to the x icon's `closeclick` event at the same time.

Here's an example that includes duplicate info window creation avoidance by tacking a boolean `hasInfoWindow` status on markers.

```
  newMarker.addListener('click', function () {
    // If a marker does not yet have an info window, create and show it
    if (newMarker['hasInfoWindow'] !== true) {
      newInfoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({content: infoContent}); 
      mapSet['infoWindowsObj'].push(newInfoWindow);
      newMarker['hasInfoWindow'] = true;
      newInfoWindow.open(mapSet, newMarker);

      // If info window is dismissed individually, fully remove object
      google.maps.event.addListener(newInfoWindow, 'closeclick', function () {
        newInfoWindow.setMap(null);
        newMarker['hasInfoWindow'] = false;
        mapSet['infoWindowsObj'].filter(arrayItem => arrayItem !== newInfoWindow);
      });
    }
  });
```

Then if you want to remove all open info windows due to a click event on a map, you can iterate through the contents of `mapSet['infoWindowsObj']` to fully remove each.

I believe this behavior lets you get away with using infowindow for most cases without having to reimplement the whole thing as per google's [custom popup example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/overlay-popup).

Answer (score -1):

this is very simple find the class of close infowindow button, that is '.gm-ui-hover-effect'

trigger to close infowindow

$('.gm-ui-hover-effect').trigger('click');