# Google maps info window use of close icon and removal of arrow

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am not an expert here but trying trial and error using the examples all over.
Currently when I click on the marker, the info window pops-up and the map also zooms in to the marker position.

```
  infowindow.setContent(content);
  map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());
  map.setZoom(4);
```

Now I am looking for two things.

1. When the user clicks the close icon on the infowindow, the map's
   zoom is reset to 2;
2. I am trying to find out a way to get rid of the arrow at the bottom of the infobox.

The link to the example is as follows:
[Example map](http://dev.amlabc.com/custom_plugins/map/test-1.html)

-Abhi

**Edit1:** 
I got the answer to my first question from Ivan! I do still need an answer for the 2nd question now. How can I get rid of the arrow at the bottom of the infobox as highlighted in red in the below image? Or is it possible to have the arrow point to left towards the marker?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Clicks the close icon on the infowindow

As described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6777885/1023562):

Use `InfoWindow` `closeclick` event:

```
var currentMark;
var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: 'im an info windows'
});
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
    infoWindow.open(map, this);
    currentMark = this;
});
google.maps.event.addListener(infoWindow,'closeclick',function(){
   map.setZoom(2);
});
```

Demo: [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/affgpsvt/6/)

### Get rid of the arrow at the bottom of the infobox

Styling InfoWindow is not easy, so I propose to take a look at 2 other possibilities, which offer much more when it comes to custom styling:

[Google utility library](https://code.google.com/p/google-maps-utility-library-v3/wiki/Libraries#InfoBox) | [Example](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infobubble/examples/example.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot Ivan! I will definitely give a try to the fist part of the close event. This is exactly what I was looking at.  For the 2nd part (getting rid of the arrow), I do not want to go for a custom infobox yet. Is it possible to have the arrow towards the left on the pointer itself?